# How to make subdirectory collections in Jekyll?

Tags: web, markdown, jekyll, liquid

I have a Jekyll site and I want to make collections **but with subdirectories**

For example, I have kind of this structure:

```
......
_projects/ # "mysite.domain/projects", contains list of available projects (based on these directory)
├── lineageos # "mysite.domain/projects/lineageos"
├── twrp # "mysite.domain/projects/twrp"
└── ungap # "mysite.domain/projects/ungap"
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I have read the [Jekyll collections docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/), but I can't understand it all and apply it for this.

Thanks! Let me know if you need more details.

Note: The things that making me confused is config file and markdown/layout structure for this kind of collections. So it will very appreciated if you tell me about this with detail :)

Comment: Umm, I also read the other question too. But still, I am confused

Comment: Can you share your _config.yaml file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the `projects` folder in the `_config.yml` and set the output to true. The sort_by is optional.

The collection folder must start with underscore `_` so rename the folder to "_projects" instead of projects.

```yaml
collections:
  projects:
     output: true
     sort_by: title
```

See the hint box of the [jekyll docu - collections](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#add-content)

> **Be sure to name your directories correctly**
> The folder must be named identically to the collection you defined in your _config.yml file, with the addition of the preceding _ character.

Comment: Subfolders can maybe handled with 'permalink' , i found there https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/920#issuecomment-315503935

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sorry, but this is not I want. With this way, it will produce "mysite.domain/projects", **but** my problem is to add more directory in _projects and list through of it.

Comment: Anyway I found another idea based on that. Something similar like that but with other way. Thanks for reply! Upvoted.

Comment: Happy, that I was able to help. Can you share your result, so we all can learn? BTW You can answer your questions yourself.

Comment: Sure. My site: https://www.hendralize.my.id. Source: https://github.com/hendralize/website. Look at the button in the header. OK, will answer the question later with this idea.